# How to add sub-properties to property group in CMFCPropertyGridProperty

Tags: mfc

How do I add properties dynamically to `CMFCPropertyGridProperty`? I know we have a method `AddProperty` to add properties but I want to add my new property as a sub-item to a property already added to `CMFCPropertyGridProperty`. I can use `GetProperty` method to get any property using index. But I am not able to add my new property as a sub-item to the property which I have retrieved.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code you're having problems with? You'd get a great answer quickly if you did. Otherwise, this question will likely be closed.

Comment: Thanks for your respone. I have got the solution. Please find my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I got it worked.

```
CMFCPropertyGridProperty* pGroup = m_wndPropList.GetProperty(Index);
CMFCPropertyGridProperty *prop = new CMFCPropertyGridProperty(_T(“SampleName”), (_variant_t) _T(“SampleValue”), _T("Custom Property"));
pGroup->AddSubItem(prop);
m_wndPropList.AdjustLayout(); // This redraws the properties
```